# Using Python codeblocks in ArcGIS to evaluate if all values in many columns is 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.5

I'm working on zoning data and I've been evaluating if the percentage for various zoning is more than 90% of the area, so I can define it as that zone in a new field, like so:

```
def ifBlock(RS, RM):
if RS >= 90:
    return "RS"
elif RM >= 90:
    return "RM" 
else:
    return "Mixed"
```

There are approximately ~40-50 lines of the above code for the different zones. However, for some of the parcels, the values for all of the zones come out to 0. I want to make a new field to identify these areas as "no data". I thought  that I could define all of the zoning columns in a list, and I wanted to write in Python something like "if all of the values in the list = 0, return no data".

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field. Then use the below code:

```
def nodataf(args,**kwargs):
    for a in args:
       for k in kwargs:
           if a == kwargs[k]:
               return "No Data"
```

List your fields.

> nodataf([!a!, !b!,!c!], k = 0)

Comment: I have many more zones than the two I listed, so it would be a lot more efficient if I could classify the zone fields as one list and write "if list = 0, return 'no data'".

Comment: Sum of the list ==O ?

Comment: @FelixIP  !a!== 0 and !b! == 0  and ...

Comment: In fact this can be done with a one-liner ‘all’.

Comment: @fatih_dur This is exactly what I meant in 1st comment, e.g. sum([!a!,!b!,!c!]), providing they are all non-negative.

Comment: @FelixIP So would it be something like I list my fields sum([!a!, !b!, !c!]), then def sum(a, b, c), and if sum = 0 return "no data"?

Comment: @wetland what does the two asterisks do?

Comment: There single parameter in a function, e.g. def retSum(aList): if sum(aList)==0: return Null next line return somethingElse

Comment: @clowdyday look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: @FelixIP I did not try your soltuion. But I think yours is more clear than my answer. Built in functions like sum have better performance also.Thanks.

Comment: @FelixIP that worked great, thank you. although instead of returning "null", I get the numerical value of the sum. it's fine because I can still select by 0's, but I wonder why it didn't return the string.

Comment: Is it a shapefile or feature class in geodatabase?